# javascript push to array named as another array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

If I have an array of strings like `stringsArray = ["arrOne","arrTwo","arrThree"]` and a list of arrays like `var arrOne = [], arrTwo = [], arrThree = []` is it possible to do something like:

```
stringsArray = ["arrOne","arrTwo","arrThree"]
var arrOne = [], arrTwo = [], arrThree = []

stringsArray[0].push(somestuff)
```

to basically push something into arrOne in this case

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to push something into arrOne in that example?

Comment: @TomRoman Yes, exactly. i'll update

Comment: Where do the strings in `stringsArray` come from? Who decides what the variable names are called? Currently, it looks like you simply need `const stringsArray = [[], [], []];`. If you don’t know the strings in advance, use an object like `const arrays = { arrOne: [], arrTwo: [], arrThree: [] };` and `arrays[stringsArray[0]].push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object as reference to the arrays.

```js
const
    stringsArray = ["arrOne","arrTwo","arrThree"],
    arrOne = [], arrTwo = [], arrThree = [],
    reference = { arrOne, arrTwo, arrThree };
    

reference[stringsArray[0]].push('somestuff');

console.log(arrOne);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative Maybe you can achieve it with `Object`.

```js
const stringsArray = ["arrOne","arrTwo","arrThree"]
// var arrOne = [], arrTwo = [], arrThree = []
// stringsArray[0].push(somestuff)
const obj = stringsArray.reduce((acc, str)=>{
  acc[str] = [];
  return acc;
}, {});

obj[stringsArray[0]].push("SomeStuff");
obj["arrTwo"].push("someStuff!");
obj.arrThree.push("Threee");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off the code you have given, you're trying to push into `arrOne` by pushing into the `stringsArray`. Your best bet is to do something like:

```
stringsArray = [[],[],[]]

stringsArray[0].push(somestuff)
```

You could then access this with something like:

```
let arrOne = [...stringsArray[0]]
```